# Laravel 5.4 field Validation already exists

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a field called title in table languages.

While creating a new user using register form, user has a option to either chose existing or create a new language. How do I make sure the language created is unique?

users table is different and languages table is different.

## my current validation code in create method (Registercontroller)

```
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => ['required','max:255','unique:users','regex:/(@org.uk)$/',],
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'title' => 'required',
```

I want to add something like: unqiue:languages but how do I do that? do I set langauge field to unique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[laravel validation for unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique)
 here is the solution what you needed . In unique validation it check new entry was unique or not what you do is this just simply given the desired table name and field from which you want to check field is unique or not

```
'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
 'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
 'email' => ['required','max:255','unique:users','regex:/(@org.uk)$/',],
 'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
 'title' => 'required|unique:languages,title',
```

hope this will help you